# How to fetch next <td> value where first <td> contains a string with PHP?

Tags: php, dom

I need to fetch value from 2nd and 3rd  where string equal to 1st . Sometimes the data is not written in the same format but they're always have time string to fetch the related values.

For example, if I search `00:30` I need `891` and `48` in turn. Or if I search `01:00`. I need `725` and `77` in turn.

I don't know how to achieve this. Please tell me what kind of method to do so. Is there any sql like method to query the related value?

**data from a url:**

```
                <table id="Tb1">
                 <tr class="odd">
                    <td>Round 00:20 O.</td>
                    <td>496</td>
                    <td>84</td>
                </tr>
            
                <tr class="even">
                    <td>Round 00:30 O.</td>
                    <td>891</td>
                    <td>48</td>
                </tr>
            
                <tr class="odd">
                    <td>Round 00:40 O.</td>
                    <td>561</td>
                    <td>08</td>
                </tr>
            
                <tr class="even">
                    <td>Round 00:50 O.</td>
                    <td>739</td>
                    <td>01</td>
                </tr>
            
                <tr class="odd">
                    <td>Round 01:00 O.</td>
                    <td>725</td>
                    <td>77</td>
                </tr>
            
                <tr class="even">
                    <td>Round 01:10 O.</td>
                    <td>029</td>
                    <td>86</td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

I tried `simple_html_dom` for this. It seems to work but I don't know how to get the related . The code below just check for the string and return the table's id.

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."simple_html_dom.php";
$html=file_get_html('www.example.com/Result.aspx?Date=29-Aug-2022');


$eles = $html->find('table');
foreach($eles as $e) {
    if(strpos($e->innertext, '00:30') !== false) {
        echo $e->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you build this HTML or are you scraping some other page

Comment: I use file_get_html() from another url.

Comment: Why use simple_html_dom instead of DOMDocument?

Comment: Coz I just know only that. Is it easier???

Comment: I don't know about "easier" - nothing is really easy with html/xml parsing... I just found DOMDocument more effective, so that's what I tend to use.